# Training not speeding up even after using GPU

Tags: pytorch, gpu, kaggle

```
transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.Resize(IMG_SIZE),
                                transforms.CenterCrop(CROP_SIZE),
                                transforms.ToTensor()]) 

class LandmarksDatasetTrain(Dataset):
    """Landmarks dataset.""" 

    def __init__(self, landmarks_frame, root_dir, transform=None):
        """
        Args:
            csv_file (string): Path to the csv file with annotations.
            root_dir (string): Directory with all the images.
            transform (callable, optional): Optional transform to be applied
                on a sample.
        """
        self.landmarks_frame = landmarks_frame
        self.root_dir = root_dir
        self.transform = transform 

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.landmarks_frame)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        if torch.is_tensor(idx):
            idx = idx.tolist()
        img_name = os.path.join(self.root_dir,self.landmarks_frame.loc[idx, 'id'][0],self.landmarks_frame.loc[idx, 'id'][1], self.landmarks_frame.loc[idx, 'id'][2], self.landmarks_frame.loc[idx, 'id'])
        img_name += ".jpg"
        image = Image.open(img_name)
        landmarks = self.landmarks_frame.loc[idx, 'landmark_id']
        sample = {'image': image, 'landmarks': landmarks}

        if self.transform:
            sample['image'] = self.transform(sample['image'])
            sample['landmarks'] = torch.tensor(sample['landmarks'])

        return sample

dataset_train = LandmarksDatasetTrain(landmarks_frame = frame,
                                      root_dir='/kaggle/input/landmark-recognition-2020/train',
                                      transform=transform)

train_loader = DataLoader(dataset_train, batch_size=4, shuffle=True, num_workers=4, drop_last=False)

class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(CROP_SIZE*CROP_SIZE*3, 64)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(64, 64)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(64, 64)
        self.fc4 = nn.Linear(64, frame['landmark_id'].nunique())

    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc3(x))
        x = self.fc4(x)
        return F.log_softmax(x, dim=1)

net = Net()
net.to(device)

for epoch in range(3): 
    optimizer = optim.Adam(net.parameters(), lr=0.001)
    for data in tqdm(train_loader):  
        X = data['image'].to(device)  
        y = data['landmarks'].to(device) 
        net.zero_grad()  
        output = net(X.view(-1,CROP_SIZE*CROP_SIZE*3))  
        loss = F.nll_loss(output, y) 
        loss.backward()  
        optimizer.step() 
    print(loss)
```

batch size is 4

data['image'] and data['landmarks'] are tensors device = torch.device("cuda:0") and deep learning library I am using is Pytorch but GPU is still not working for me. Its usage shows 5% and total time for 1 epoch 3.5 to 4 hours

Will be really helpful if someone points out my mistake.

Attaching an image of resource usage and GPU config.
[image]

Attaching image for showing that GPU is on
[image]

Here is the link to my notebook
https://www.kaggle.com/hiteshsom/google-landmark-recognition

Comment: If you run this statement, what is the result? `device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')`

Comment: Gives answer

Running on the GPU

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010, I have just added anpther image in my question showing GPU is running

Comment: Can you please just type out the result of: `torch.cuda.is_available()` ? It should say True or False

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010, Its printing True

Comment: I don't know the size of your images and cropped images but I think your model is so small (couple thousands parameters) that there's not much the GPU can improve with respect to the CPU. You're probably mostly I/O bound. Try using much bigger Linear layer, and see whether that improves the GPU speed / CPU speed ratio

Comment: @trialNerror
cropped image size = 100
image size = 150

Comment: @trialNerror I have increased image size to 500 and cropped size to 300. also I have increase parameters in training I have 8 layers (64, 128, 256, 128, 64, 32, 64, 57042). The GPU utilization did go up to 20% but the total time for one epoch is increased from 3.5 hr to 5 hr roughly

Comment: Yes it was indeed expected that the training time would increase. But what I wanted to show was that your GPU is probably underwhelmed by the number of operations to perform. You can most likely afford to perform more complex operations (like bigger fc layers or deep convolutions, you're working on images after all). JPG is already among the fastest file format to load/decompress, but you can try to use pin_memory (https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/when-to-set-pin-memory-to-true/19723) to reduce the data transfer bottleneck